# Raspberrry Pi brick temperature sensor python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, sensors, temperature

I am trying for 2 weeks now to make an temperature sensor. First I used the D18B20 sensor, but I couldn't make it to end, so I chose an "Brick" sensor.
Everything is alright , I did the setup but I am completly stuck at the phyton part, I copyed the code and when I try to run it (`sudo python x.py`) it says:

```
"SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character "\xe2" in file x.py on line 51, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

Can some one help me please ? I really want to finish this project already.

Comment: As you have chosen to withhold not only line 51, but all of the lines of code, what kind of help are you expecting?

Comment: Like above, the code is required to analyze, but my assumption is that somewhere on line 51 there is a character that isn't what you think it is. This happens sometimes when copying and pasting. For instance, a quote (
U+0022) may actually be U+201C or U+201D.

Comment: Yes , i checked and it it , instead of ------ is an full line (it's full , no gaps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use Python 2? Iy you want to put UTF-8 characters to source file you have to specify it's encoding as utf-8. Just put this line at the very top of the file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```